# Where is Hotkeys for Desktop shortcut stored in Windows registry and how to change it?

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, hotkeys

When we assign a keyboard shortcut/hotkey from properties menu, where is it stored in the Windows registry? And how can we edit it using command line/ Batch file?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the shortcuts are stored anywhere specifically, but we can edit shortcut hotkeybusing a VBScript and use it in Batch:

```
Dim WshShell,objShortcut
Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set objShortcut = WshShell.CreateShortcut("SHORTCUT PATH")
objShortcut.Hotkey = "YOUR HOTKEY"
```

Comment: Well I have a limited knowledge in VBScript and therefore I was not able to directly implement this code, however I researched online and found something that works:

Set link = Shell.CreateShortcut(DesktopPath & "\test.lnk")
link.HotKey = "CTRL+ALT+Z"

Thanks for nudging in the right direction, though